# Raspberry Pi auto-reload webpage solution

Tags: midori

I have my raspberry pi set up, I intend to use it as a "kiosk". The pi will not need interaction, It will just display a webpage.

Until now I have been using meta tags to refresh the page evey three minutes, however, if there is a problem with the internet and the page cannot connect it will not attempt to connect again as it cannot load the page.

Is there any way to display the webpage (using midori) and automatically refresh the page through the browser every three minutes? This way if there is a internet problem it will simply not display the page for three minutes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
midori -a http://sitename **-i 120** -e Fullscreen
```

will refresh inactive page every 120 sec.